# normal distribution where the mean is another normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

Say $x\sim N(\theta,\sigma^2)$, where $\theta\sim N(\mu,\tau^2)$. It feels like we can just say $x\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2+\tau^2)$. But how can I show this? Thanks.

Comment: You're essentially describing a Bayesian linear regression with conjugate priors, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/319152).

Comment: @Durden This is a simpler problem than linear regression.

Comment: One approach is to write the joint distribution $f(x,\theta) = f(x|\theta).f(\theta)$, and compute the marginal for $x$ (in effect, to "integrate out" $\theta$, though actual integration can be sidestepped). If you know facts about normal location mixtures of normals, you can do it more directly.